# from multithreading.decorators import measure_time - Why thet dont works?

Tags: python

```
import time
```

Pycharm for some reason highlights the .decorators, but I install all

```
from multithreading.decorators import measure_time # <-- Problem with thet line


def tick():
    print('tick')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('tock')


@measure_time
def main():
    for _ in range(3):
        tick()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWHKb.png)

why decorators and measure_time are underlined

Comment: There is no multithreading.decorators module in your Python environment

Comment: I cant install it and Python Interpreter - 3.10

Comment: Well, if you can't install it (whatever **it** is) you won't be able to import it

Answer (score -1):

Create file:

> decorators.py

```
import time
from functools import wraps


def async_measure_time(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start
        print(f'Executed {func} in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds')
        return result

    return wrap


def measure_time(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start
        print(f'Executed {func} in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds')
        return result

    return wrap
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).